# Gnuplot asymmetric xy errorbars

Tags: gnuplot

I need some help with Gnuplot 4.4 - I've been trying to get 2D data scatter plotted with errorbars in both the x and y dimensions.

Both x and y dimensions have high/low errorbars, that is the errorbars are not symmetric, so each data point uses six values (x,y,xlow,xhigh,ylow,yhigh).  Gnuplot's man pages say this is possible and I've found [examples on the net](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile-e.html) - both cases suggest using data files with six records for each data point (the (x,y,xlow,xhigh,ylow,yhigh) format) but I can't for the life of me get Gnuplot to behave.

The best I can do when plotting a single test point (1.0  3.0  0.25 0.5 0.25 0.5) is to get a plot of the test point with disembodied errorbars floating in nearby space.

Comment: Can you post some example code/data which illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason your error bars are "disembodied" is that your x (1.0) is not between xlow (.25) and xhigh (.5). Your y (3.0) is also not between your ylow (.25) and yhigh (0.5).

If you want the lows and highs to represent the *difference* from the central variable, you should use a command like this:

```
plot "test.dat" u 1:2:($1-$3):($1+$4):($2-$5):($2+$6) with xyerrorbars t "test point"
```

Running this on your test file, I get the following plot:

[image: Plot of questioner's example point]

Comment: I wonder why it is implented this way in gnuplot. Errorbars should never be "disembodied" and it's more work to write `value + error` than just `error`.

Comment: @con-f-use: Error bars could in general be asymmetric.